# minimum of integers

Tags: java

```
package variousprograms;
import java.util.*;
public class InputStats 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;

        System.out.println("First Integer ");
        a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Second Integer ");
        b = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Third Integer ");
        c = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Fourth Integer ");
        d = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Fifth Integer ");
        e = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Maximum is " + Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(a,b), c), d), e));
        System.out.println("Minimum is " + Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(a,b), c), d), e));
        System.out.println("Mean is " + (a + b + c + d + e)/5.0);    
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to find the minimum, maximum, and mean of a set of five integers using five variables for each integer. The problem is that I am supposed to use four variables instead of five, and I cannot use control statements such as if or loop.

How should I change the code I already wrote?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Does your instructor consider a ternary operator to be a control statement?

Comment: I can't use ternary operators

Comment: This is a ridiculous problem. The [Math.max](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.max%28int%2Cint%29) method uses a ternary operator: `public static long max(long a, long b) { return (a >= b) ? a : b; }`.

Comment: storing values while progressing through the code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with variables for the current input, min, max, and total. Just keep re-using the same variable for input, and update the other three variables before you get the next input from the user.

To keep track of the maximum value without if statements, you'll have to do something like:

```
max = Math.max(max, input);
```

And something similar for the minimum value.

Comment: So would the variables be: input, min, max, and total?

Comment: @P.Icker Yes. After the first input, you can just set min, max, and total equal to the first value entered. After the second input, you have to update each of those three with a new value, and so on.

Comment: Could you possibly post the code? That would be helpful!

Comment: @P.Icker No, this looks like homework. I'm sure you can get it from a few hints.

Comment: I approached this while studying for a test. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the inputs any longer than necessary, just store the results as you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int min;
    int max;
    long total;
    int val;

    System.out.println("First Integer ");
    val = input.nextInt();
    min = val;
    max = val;
    total = val;

    System.out.println("Second Integer ");
    val = input.nextInt();
    min = Math.min(val, min);
    max = Math.max(val, max);
    total += val;

    System.out.println("Third Integer ");
    val = input.nextInt();
    min = Math.min(val, min);
    max = Math.max(val, max);
    total += val;

    System.out.println("Fourth Integer ");
    val = input.nextInt();
    min = Math.min(val, min);
    max = Math.max(val, max);
    total += val;

    System.out.println("Fifth Integer ");
    val = input.nextInt();
    min = Math.min(val, min);
    max = Math.max(val, max);
    total += val;

    System.out.println("Maximum is " + max);
    System.out.println("Minimum is " + min);
    System.out.println("Mean is " + total / 5.0);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without if statements?

Comment: What is the code like without invoking methods that use ternary operators? :D I stand by my statement that the premise of the problem is flawed.

Comment: Shouldn't `total` be a `long`, instead of an `int`, so that it can't overflow while you are adding to it?